# Count answers based on unique part number with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have been tasked to determine a list of reference materials based on part numbers for various assemblies. In one column I have part numbers and a simple (Yes or No) response in another based on what I find.

There are thousands of part numbers that must be searched and validated manually, unfortunately. With a lot of duplicates.

How can I count the "No's" only if they have not been counted before based on the part number in another column?

[image]

For example. No is listed for potato twice. I only want my counter to count one "no" for potato because it has been counted before hand.

I'm having trouble because I can't use a countif funtion to count the number of instances that the value "potato" in in the part number column. I want to count the percentage of part numbers that do not have references as a ratio to the number of unique part numbers within the entire system. Duplicates counted will skew this number drastically.

Comment: Your question is on the vague side. `COUNTIF()` might be relevant, but since I really don't know *what* you are trying to count it is hard to know for sure. Please explain.

Comment: If "Grape" is "Yes" in one line, will it be in all lines?

Comment: Allow me to clarify..I want to count the number of "No's" in the reference column and only count the no that do not appear multiple times in reference to the part number. For instance in the example image, I only want to count no one time for potato, even if it occurs twice.

Comment: Do you have Blank Cells (NO, YES, Blank)?

Comment: No Blank cells. Every cell will be filled with either "YES" or "NO"

Comment: So you're just trying to identify if each one has a yes or a no against it? Why do you need to count them/? Please post sample data.

Comment: I would like to show the percentage of models that need to be created for a mechanical system. Obviously, if I create a part for an assembly it already exists the next time I need it. I already know that counting the amount of "No" for every instance of no will not show the true percentage of models we do not have.

Comment: Create a new table with three columns, column 1 containing a list of your unique parts, column 2 for Yes and column 3 for No. Now paste this into the first cell of column 2, drag accross to column 3 and down till your hearts content! `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,$D3,$B$1:$B$10,$E$1)>=1,"1","0")` - where `$A$1:$A$10` is your part numbers, `$D3` is the first value in a unique list of your part numbers, `$B$1:$B$10` is your reference and `$E$1` contains Yes - with `$F$1` containing No.

Comment: use this formula =SUM(--(B1:B7="NO")/COUNTIFS(A1:A7,A1:A7,B1:B7,B1:B7))  column B (Yes,NO) column A(parts) change reference to correspond your data